# concat the output of the subquery?

Tags: mysql

i have a query which would return values but i need them as a single output separated by commas..

So i tried to concat the output with the comma but it didn't work?

```
select id from videos where duration=0;  /// this would return some rows
```

I tried concat and concat_ws  but didn't work

```
select concat(select concat(id,',') from videos where duration=0);
select concat((select id from videos where duration=0),',');
select concat_ws(',',(select id from videos where duration=0));
```

i need the id's of all rows with the comma separtor

for example the output should be 1,4,6,78,565

any ideas?

Comment: If you are using `GROUP_CONCAT` keep in mind it is limited to 1024. So if your string gets cut off, raise the limit (I tend to overlook that from time to time ;))

Comment: That's what exactly happened when i tried that yesterday.. My query would return more than 2500 values.. How can i increase the limit?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is what [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) does.

```
select group_concat(id) as video_list
from videos 
where duration=0
```

Comment: @RajkumarGour yes, limit doesn't work, but there are workarounds, see my answer below.

Comment: group_concat does not require GROUP_BY?

Comment: @sureshvv - Not if you don't want to group by anything. No

Answer (score 11):

Try using `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
     GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
         [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
             [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
         [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 8):

Use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) :

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM
  videos
WHERE
  duration=0
```

Answer (score 0):

To work around the inability to use `LIMIT` with `GROUP_CONCAT` you can group by the results of a sub query

This query breaks up your video ids into groups of 20 (but it could be REALLY slow on some datasets)

```
select group_concat(v.id) as video_list
from videos as v
where v.duration=0
group by (
    select floor(count(v2.id)/20)
    from videos as v2
    where v2.duration=0
    and v2.id <= v.id
)
```

Alternatively, if you have a lot of results but don't want such a slow query, you can increase to the size of your `group_concat_max_len` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) up to your `max_allowed_packet` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet), if this is still not long enough, you would have to increase the max_allowed_packet size as well.